# Private accessor for signed assembly together with InternalsVisibleTo

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, strongname

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 unit testing features in a project of mine. I'm running into problems trying to create a private accessor.

MyProject:

- The strong name key is password protected (.pfx file instead of .snk)
- I use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to provide access to internals for MyProject.Tests
- Verification of the key is skipped (on development systems) with `sn -Vr ...` to allow instrumentation in Release builds; for the purpose of obtaining code coverage. This is because the instrumentation part of Visual Studio [does not support password protected keys](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2432354-make-it-easier-to-enable-code-coverage-with-signed).

MyProject.Tests:

- Signed with the same key as MyProject, to allow use of InternalsVisibleTo
- I'm trying to generate a private accessor in this project to test some private methods.

When trying to compile the test project with the newly added private accessor, I'm getting the following error message:

> Error occurred during processing of assembly 'MyProject.dll': Unable
>   to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair.

I've browsed the internet regarding the error message, but the only solution I could find was to disable signing on the test project. Doing so would mean that I am no longer able to use `InternalsVisibleTo`. It might work  if I rewrite all my existing unit tests for internal members to use shadowed types as well, but obviously I don't want to do so.

Are there any better options?

---

In case it matters: the strong name key is password protected because the source control system is fairly public, but I wanted to prevent access from anybody outside the development team.